# For statement in Django templates doesn't work

Tags: python, html, django

I have a problem with the `{% for %}` loop in my jango templates.

**models.py:**

```py
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Country")
    published = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Nodes(models.Model):
    node = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Node")
    panelists = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.node
```

**views.py:**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from countries.models import Country
from countries.models import Nodes

def nodes(request):
    return render(request, 'country/country.html', {'nodes' : Nodes.objects.all()})

def countries(request):
    return render(request, 'countries/countries.html', {'countries' : Country.objects.all()})

def country(request, country_id):
    return render(request, 'country/country.html', {'country' : Country.objects.get(id=country_id)})
```

And in my template **country.html** I have:

```
<h2 class="title">{{ country.title }}</h2>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          {% for n in nodes %}
          <li>{{ n.node }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

And that doesn't work. Could You help me please?
If I change **country.html** file like this:

```
<h2 class="title">{{ country.title }}</h2>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      {% for n in nodes %}
      <h2>TEST</h2>
      <li>{{ n.node }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I can't see "TEST" either. So, it seems that the whole for statement is not working.

Comment: Maybe, It's because your nodes is empty. You hasn't records in Nodes table in db.

Comment: This is confusing; you have two views that refer to country.html. Which one are you using here?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: I'm sure that db isn't empty. And "doesn't work" mean that nothing happen, app work perfectly, but records from Nodes table doesn't display. It is as if the program omitted this piece of code.

Comment: Can we see your urls.py file and then tell us what url are you calling? Give us the exact url.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to go `example.com/country/country_id` you won't be able to print the nodes, since they aren't in the context dic in your view function. 
Try doing it like this:

```
def country(request, country_id):
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        nodes = Nodes.objects.all()
        context_dict['username'] = nodes

        country =  Country.objects.filter(id=country_id)
        context_dict['posts'] = country

    except Country.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'country/country.html', context_dict, )
```

One of the mistakes I think you have made is `Country.objects.get(id=country_id)` since you are just getting the ID and I could see in your template you are trying to get the Country title. The best thing to do is, since you are trying to get the page for a specific `country_id`, you have to use the `filter` when you are trying to query the Country model. And don't forget about the `urls.py`. 
It should look something like this

`url(r'^country/(?P<country_id>\d+)/$', views.country, name='country'),`

Give it a try and let me know, if it still doesn't work and what kind of errors are you getting.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved the problem. I didn't know I can't make two function relate to the same template. Now **views.py** looks like this:

```py
def country(request, country_id):
    return render(request, 'country/country.html', {'country' : Country.objects.get(id=country_id), 'nodes' : Nodes.objects.all()})
```

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33984253/edit) button to update your question, or the comment section to respond to comments.

Comment: What makes you think you can't have two view functions that use the same template?